# Pyqt5 Threading Signaling multiple triggers

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

Worker:

```
class ScrubWorker(QRunnable):
signals = Signals()
number = []

def __init__(self, number, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ScrubWorker, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.number = number

def run(self):
    self.signals.results.emit(self.number[0])
    self.autoDelete()
    # ## END PADNC
```

ThreadPool:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def get_results(self, number):
    print(number)

def check_against_dncs(self):
    try:
        header = ["NUMBER", "FTC", "PADNC", "MADNC"]
        numbers = []
        with open("check.csv", "r") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                numbers.append([row[0], 0, 0, 0])
        print(len(numbers))
        print(f" Running {self.thread.maxThreadCount()} Threads")

        workers = {}
        for row in numbers:
            print(f"Spawned workers[{row[0]}]")
            workers[row[0]] = ScrubWorker(row)
            workers[row[0]].signals.results.connect(self.get_results)
            self.thread.start(workers[row[0]])
```

Each worker is unique, I've forgone naming them as I tought the connect statement was being repeated for the same named variable. The output for each worker is returned multiple times. Not the same number of times for each thread either.
Any insights to why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also ensure that you're properly [formatting your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and indentation is correct by always checking the preview of the question before submitting any change.

Comment: The `signals` object is a class atribute, so a single instance of it will be shared by all future instances of `ScrubWorker`. This means that any connections made to its signals will be completely independant of the worker objects themselves. Since you connect to the same slot for each worker, and never explicitly disconnect anything, then, for each invokation of `check_against_dncs`, that slot will be called `len(numbers)` times whenever `results` is emitted. And the signal connections could just keep growing without limit, because deleting a worker doesn't disconnect anything.